# Name convention for functor and natural transformation composition

Tags: category-theory

If there are functors $H: D \to C; F,G: C \to D$ and $K: B \to C$ and a natural transformation $\alpha: F \xrightarrow{.} G$ then we can construct 2 new natural transformations:

Aka "left composition"
$$H \alpha : H F \xrightarrow{.} H G $$
and "right composition"
$$ \alpha K : F K \xrightarrow{.} G K $$

I was not able to find the naming convention for these ones and called them as **left and right compositions** but not sure that there are correct namings. Could anybody help me in the finding correct ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [whiskering](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/whiskering); you can show that it is the same as the horizontal composition of $\alpha$ with $1_H:H\Rightarrow H$ (for your "left composition") or with $1_K:K\Rightarrow K$ (for your "right composition").

Comment: Thank you for the link. It is exactly that I need. I also found the same question in stack exchange and most probably the question has to be removed as the dublicate